# Reload CRF NER model of StanfordCoreNLP pipeline

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am making a web application (GUI) for building a CRF NER model instead of manually anotating CSV files. When the user collects a number of training files, he should be able to generate a new model and try it.
The issue I have is with reloading of model. When I assign a new value to pipeline, like

```
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
```

the model stays the same. I tried to clear the annotation pool with

```
StanfordCoreNLP.clearAnnotatorPool()
```

but nothing changes. Is this possible at all or I have to restart my whole application every time to get this to work?

**EDIT** (Clarification):

I have 2 methods in same class: `nerString()` and `train()`. Something like this:

```
class NerService {

  private var pipeline: StanfordCoreNLP = null

  loadPipelines()

  private def loadPipelines(): Unit = {

    val props = new Properties()
    props.setProperty("tokenize.class", "BosnianTokenizer")
    props.setProperty("ner.model", "conf/NER/classifiers/ner-ba-model.ser.gz") // NER CRF model
    props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "false")    
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner")

    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(propsNER)    
  }

  def nerString(tekst: String): List[TokenNER] = {
    val document = new Annotation(tekst)
    pipeline.annotate(document)
    ...
  }

  /////////////// train new NER model ///////////////////////
  private val trainProps = StringUtils.propFileToProperties("conf/NER/classifiers/ner-ba-training.prop")
  private val serializeTo = "conf/NER/classifiers/ner-ba-model.ser.gz" // save at location...
  private val inputDir = new File("conf/NER/classifiers/input")
  private val fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.tsv")
  private val dirFilter = TrueFileFilter.TRUE

  def train(): Unit = {
    val allFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(inputDir, fileFilter, dirFilter).asScala
    val trainFileList = allFiles.map(_.getPath).mkString(",")
    trainProps.setProperty("trainFileList", trainFileList)
    val flags = new SeqClassifierFlags(trainProps)

    val crf = new CRFClassifier[CoreLabel](flags)    
    crf.train()    
    crf.serializeClassifier(serializeTo)

    loadPipelines()
  }
}
```

The `loadPipelines()` is used to re-assign the pipeline when the new NER model is created.
How do I know that the model isn't updated? I have a text that I include manually and see the difference with and without it..

Comment: Could you clarify how the web app works?  When the user builds a new model do they specify a path to where the new model is, and then you're setting props.setProperty("ner.model", "/new/path/to/model"); before rebuilding the pipeline?

Comment: I added additional explanation, thank you for your time. :)

Comment: I've found a solution, now I'm generating new model with a timestamp appended to it's name. Also deleting older model... :D